# Characters disappearing when concatenating strings

Tags: python-3.x

The objective is to take a number of cells with strings and concatenate them in the following format: 'string 1|string 2". The code I am using does this but the resulting string is significantly shorter than it should be.

Non-concatenated length: 7,752,545 characters

Concatenated length: 2,118 characters

Briefly, the dataset has two columns. One contains the names of different geographical regions and the other contains company names. I need to have region as the category with all of the company names concatenated as described above.

What would be causing a majority of the strings to not appear in the formatted data set?

```py
## This is what is used to concatenate the strings
def preprocessing(dataset, title, keywords):
    dataset[keywords] = dataset[keywords].replace(' ', '_', regex = True)
    df = dataset.groupby(title)[keywords].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(str(x).split()))
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df[keywords] = df[keywords].replace('_', ' ', regex = True)
    return(df)
## 
region_prep = preprocessing(geo_region, 'Region', 'Company Name')
```

DESIRED RESULTS

With a file like this:

geo_region

```
Company Name   Region
walmart        north america
amazon         north america
google         north america
```

I am looking for a result that looks like:

region_prep

```
north america    walmart|amazon|google
```

Comment: Could you write what `geo_region` value is?

Comment: geo_region is just a bigger version of the dataset with company name and region in it. I'll mark it accordingly

Comment: Could you provide some example value for it? E.g. `geo_region = {'Company Name': 'amazon', 'Region': 'north america'}`. I mean what are the keys and values types: lists, strings or smth else?

Comment: There's no such data type as "column" in python. Please, provide what data objects you are working with in `geo_region`.

Comment: region prep is a dataframe with index region and company name as an object